# Миграции с помощью South и доступ к модели

Tags: миграция, django

Доброго времени суток!
Я применяю для миграций Django-проекта South, и возникла такая проблема - в одной из миграций в методе forwards мне надо обратиться к некоторой модели. Если просто импортировать модель и что-то поделать с экземплярами этой модели, а затем сохранить - сохранения в базу не уйдут. Для этого официальная справка South рекомендует использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
  instances = orm.Modelname.objects.all()
```

Однако применяя эту миграцию получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: The model 'Modelname' from the app 'Data' is not available in this migration. (Did you use orm.ModelName, not orm['app.ModelName']?)
```

На всякий случай пробую писать

```
instances = orm['Data.Modulename'].objects.all()
```

И тоже ничего - та же ошибка, только без уточнения в скобках.
Помогите пожалуйста - как всеж достучаться до модели и поработать с ней?
Версия South 0.7.6, миграцию применяю к приложению Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательность миграций можно задавать в [зависимостях](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html#reverse-dependencies). Также операции над данными нужно делать не на «сухом» прогоне:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    if not db.dry_run:
        instances = orm['Data.Modulename'].objects.all()
```

Comment: Так вроде не на сухом запускаю, все равно ругается

Comment: Решилось. Модели не прописали в миграции